# How to find the maximum of (x+y) for the given equation ax + by = c where a,b,c are constants and x , y >= 0 and all are integers?

Tags: c++, math

#### Problem:

Given the equation ax + by = c and the values of a,b,c.

a,b,c are positive integers in range 1 and 1000000000000000000 or (10^18).

We have to calculate maximum of x+y.

x and y should be non-negative integers.

#### My Attempt:

A brute-force solution is checking all values of x and y. But the complexity here is O(n) which would take more than several billion years to compute for large input.

#### Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long x,y,a,b,c,mx;
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    mx = 0;
    for (x = 0; a*x<=c; x++)
    {
        y = c - a*x;
        if(y<0||y%b) continue;
        y/=b;
        mx = max(mx, x+y);
    }

    cout<<mx<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

#### Task:

We have to reduce the complexity to O(log(n)) or O(1).

Could you please help me?

Comment: Is this problem description from another website? Or is this a homework exercise? Please look up binary search and ternary search, maybe that can solve the task.

Comment: @martijnn2008 I did not found the exact problem anywhere, but this is a sub-part of a problem in [codeforces](http://codeforces.com/contest/625/problem/A).

Comment: Rearranging, `x = (c - by) / a`. So `x + y = c / a - (b - a) y / a`. You need to maximise the thing on the right, which is linear in `y`. Apart from checking for cases where `x` or `y` are negative that doesn't seem hard.

Comment: For O(log(n)) you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm, but using some basic linear algebra this problems seems to be O(1).

Comment: isn't this a middle school problem?

Comment: @lisyarus I know binary search well. But tell me on which variable I have to do that? `x` or `y`? What would be the calculation? That means when I would go left and when I would go right?

Comment: @user3528438 It could be for your region. But whats up? Is this made it off-topic?

Comment: @manetsus sort of. it's more of an algebra problem rather than programming https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Comment: That's a diophantine equation. You can find a solution via the Euclidean algorithm. The other solutions are related to that one in a simple, known way, the finding of which is left as an exercise.

Comment: @AlanStokes Linear on y means O(n), same complexity as in my code.

Comment: @alcedine May be you had missed something. Diophantine equation had 
`ax + by = 1`.

Comment: @user3528438 See, you linked a link where "Programming" has. :)

Comment: @manetsus see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html), especially bottom of the page. `ax + by = c` in integers can be divided by `gcd(a, b)` to get `mx + ny = 1` (as long as the first problem had a solution in integers).

Comment: @alcedine but here all are integers and only integer solutions are accepted. So, you could only do this when `a%c=0` and `b%c=0` are preserved. Here `%` indicates the remainder after division.

Comment: Linear means you can trivially solve it in O(1) if you bother to think about it.

Comment: @manetsus They will be. In fact, it must be that `c == gcd(a,b)`, otherwise there is no integer solution (you can see why if you consider what happens to the equation -- `a / gcd(a,b)` is an integer, `b / gcd(a, b)` is an integer, but `c / gcd(a,b)` is not, so `x` and `y` can't be -- no power in the 'verse will make an linear combination of integers with integer coefficients yield a noninteger.)

Comment: @AlanStokes Oh, sorry, I just messed up in too much pressure on reply. However, The point where I could not get you is: what should I do with the equation `x + y = c / a - (b - a) y / a`?

Comment: @alcedine Say, `a = 12 , b = 15, c = 249` and `gcd(a,b) = 3` which is not equal to `c`. but there exists solution.

Comment: @manetsus Ah, yes, you are correct. I misread the WolframWorld page I linked. Actually `c` has to be *divisible* by `gcd(a,b)`, it doesn't have to *be* `gcd(a,b)`. But the page *does* give a solution.

Comment: @alcedine which page did you link? I could not find it.

Comment: @manetsus http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html -- it was behind the word "here" a few comments back.

Answer (score 2):

ax + by = c can be rewritten as y = -(a/b)x + (c/b)
Since a, b and c are constants, this can be plotted onto a graph.

Since a, b, c > 0 the gradient of this function is always negative and the y intercept positive. It should become intuitively clear that the largest value for x+y is near the y intercept if the gradient < -1 and close to the x intercept if the gradient > -1. Using this it should be easier to optimize out all the extra values of x and y you have to try to solve this.

Comment: Tell me how to solve it with coding. If I needed any graphical approach, then I would ask it in [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @manetsus I'm using the graphical approach to try to show you something, the first values you find starting from either the y intercept if the gradient is < -1 will be the largest values of x + y, the first values you find starting from x intercept if the gradient is > -1 will be the largest values of x + y.

Comment: This is not the exact solution, just like a suggestion for starting, right?

Comment: This would work... how is it not an 'exact' solution?

Comment: I don't have time to write it out for you :3 this is the best I can do.

Comment: @manetsus SO is not a free coding service. You should know that by now with your rep.

Comment: @Someone It seemed to me that your approach needs just a few lines of codes which might not need big effort than making me understand in other way. However, can you tell me the direction? I simply can not get your approach.

Comment: @AlanStokes Obviously I know. But it seems to me that his approach needs just a few lines of codes which might not need big effort than making me understand in other way. If you do not need much effort to do coding then it would not need free coding service. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, im not sure if my approach is fruitful, but:

ax + by = c

We can change that a bit to:

y = (c/b) - (a/b) * x

with a, b and c > 0 I can change that to:

y = -m*x + t   (with m and t > 0)

That should look familar, as its just a straight line with negative gradient.
We are interested in the maximum max(x+y), so basically:

f(x) = y + x

=> f(x) = x - m*x + t

Now to find a maximum of that equation, I would calculate f'(x) and look when its 0, but that is a bit fruitless now...

f'(x) = 1-m = 0

And now i dont know how to continue without loosing it :)
Maybe someone else can jump in.

Comment: I also stuck here in your approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear [Diophantine equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html) in two variables. The linked page provides a means of finding one solution. The main points are:

- `ax + by = c` can be divided through by `gcd(a,b)` to yield `a'x + b'y = c'`
- `c'` should be an integer -- if not, a solution does not exist
- `a'x' + b'y' = 1` can then be solved using the Euclidean algorithm (see link)
- now `x = c'x'` and `y = c'y'`, since `a'(c'x) + b'(c'y) = c'`

Now when a single solution `(x0, y0)` is known, the other solutions to the primed equation have the form `(x0 + b'k, y0 - a'k)` for all integer `k` ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations)). You want to maximize the sum of the variables.

The sum for the single solution (`k = 0`) is `x0 + y0`, and for the general solution (any `k`) is `(x0 + b'k) + (y0 - a'k) = (x0 + y0) + (b' - a')k`. But you're constrained to only positive solutions, so you only have a certain range of acceptable `k`: the union of the range of `k` where `x0 + b'k > 0` and the range where `y0 - a'k > 0`. Solve both inequalities to find your range.

Now the goal function is linear in `k` -- either growing in `k` (for `b' - a'  > 0`), in which case you want `k` to be as large as possible, or vice versa. But you're constrained to the aforementioned range of `k` only, so your solution is simply the maximum or minimum of the allowed set, depending on the sign of `b' - a'`.

The solution to the primed equation corresponds directly to the solution to the unprimed equation, as they differ only by a constant scaling factor (`x + y = c'(x' + y')`).

Remember to multiply by `c'` to get the unprimed solution.

Comment: Yes, I spent time in your approach. But the problem is `egcd` gives negative numbers too. However, in `(x + kv, y - ku)`, what are the properties of `u` and `v`? If they are too small they would not work and I need only non-negative solutions of `(x,y)`,

Comment: @manetsus Sorry, I was hasty in compiling information from different sources and some things didn't get properly defined. `u` and `v` are `a'` and `b'`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @manetsus you mean the initial solution has negative values? Just hit it with the formula for the other solutions so that they're no longer negative.

Comment: then how long should I iterate? It seems it still O(n), because, I have to iterate.

Comment: Should I analytically find my spot every time? That means different input, different program!!

Comment: How could I find `k` algebraically?

Comment: Any value that satisfy this equation would lead to the solution for `x`?

Comment: It would lead to a positive value for `x`. Go too far and `y` will drop below zero in turn, of course. You can find the range of `k` for which both `x` and `y` are positive this way. I'll let you figure out which `k` corresponds to your maximum. There is no iteration involved.

Comment: say, I have to get the 'range' of `k` by 'iteration', right? and the range could be huge, say 10^17. Then how could you claim that "no iteration involved"?

Comment: You get the range of `k` without iteration.

Comment: Okay, say I have the range of `k` in O(1), then? How to get the value of `k` which satisfies the maximum from this huge range?

Comment: The correct `k` emerges from consideration of the formula for other solutions.

Comment: @alcedine Is your `k` an integer?

Comment: Yes. Only integer `k` yield solutions to the Diophantine.

Comment: So you're saying that OP should iterate over *all* `k` in order to eventually find a solution for his maximization problem? I have the feeling that you completely ignored the `max x+y` part of the task.

Comment: With `a`, `b` and `c` being between `0` and `10^18`, that's a mighty large search space. I don't think that Diophantine equations help a lot here, even when you can find valid solutions for `x` and `y` that ignore `max x+y`.

Comment: No. The range of allowed `k` can be solved from the inequality I gave. The maximum can be found by considering how the value of the `max` depends on `k`.

Comment: Do you have any proof on that? You don't need to code it, but give the mathematical boundaries, algebraically. The whole thing more looks like an [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) [ILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) optimization problem to me, rather than solvable with a comparably simple solution such as yours.

Comment: The new maximum corresponding to `k` is `(x + b'k) + (y - a'k) = (x + y) + (b' - a')k`, therefore if `(b' - a') > 0` then the largest valid `k` is the solution and vice versa.

Comment: Actually, you may have to consider `k > 0` and `k < 0` separately, but that's still `O(1)` values to test.

Comment: Which, again, is an optimization problem in itself, not solvable algebraically. `x + y` is still not maximized, and now your `k` depends on it. Doesn't make too much sense to me. Can you clarify that on an *explicit* level? You seem to think of a solution here; pray spill it.

Comment: Which bit is a (non-trivial) optimization problem? The range of valid `k`?

Comment: `max x+y`, as stated above.

Comment: The solution that corresponds to the maximum is the solution corresponding to either the smallest or the greatest integral `k` in the allowed range, because `d/dk [(x + y) + (b' - a')k] = b' - a'`.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to maximize `(x + b'k, y - a'k)` in your answer? Where does the above formula you're deriving come from? And what does OP do with `b' - a'`? Is this `k` that maximizes `x+y`? And if yes, do you just multiply the solution `(x + b'k_opt, y - a'k_opt)` by `gcd(a,b)` and you're done? Or what's the bottom line of your reasoning?

Comment: The first bit I've addressed in a previous comment that you must have missed. As to the second bit, I've edited the answer to make the distinction between the primed and unprimed solution clearer.

Comment: I read all the comments. Your reasoning is kind of fluffy about that part. I don't find your answer sufficient in that respect, even with the edit. You should consider describing the solution on a simple example, *from beginning to end*, or show the algebraic solution of the problem in the answer text. If its as simple as the comments suggest, I guess you should be able to come up with a convincing example in a mere couple of minutes, I'm sure.

Comment: The complete derivation is in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103057/discussion-between-alcedine-and-jan-winkler).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds indeed like a job for [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). Your problem can be transformed into a standard ILP of the form

```
maximize     : c^T x
subject to   : A x + s = b
slip variable: s >= 0
and          : x in Z^n
```

With `x_orig` and `y_orig` being your `x` and `y`, `b_orig` being your `b`, and `c_orig` being your `c`:

```
x = [x_orig y_orig]
A = [a_orig 0; 0 b_orig]
b = [c_orig]
c = [1 1]
```

Now assume

```
s = 0 // valid
```

and treat it as an ILP in standard form. So you get:

```
maximize     : x_orig + y_orig
subject to   : a_orig * x_orig + b_orig * y_orig = c_orig
```

And since `x in Z^n`, all values of `x_orig` and `y_orig` stay within non-negative integers.

To solve this, there exists a multitude of tools. This problem is NP-hard, so I disagree with the comments from above about solving it in `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the two quantity is constant i.e C. We their sum is maximum when they are equal .

```
ax = by = c/2
```

Now determine x and y. the sum of x and y can be maximum.